# how 128 int after narrow casting to byte becomes -128

Tags: java

i know in java Byte has 8 bit memory , that is from -128 to 127. I also know the concept of narrowing casting. and int lost some precision. But can some one help me understand the following

```
    public class PrimitiveTypes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Byte byteVar= (byte) 128;

        System.out.println(byteVar);

    }
}


o/p is -128
```

please dont tell me because of cycle of 127 it shows -128 .
I need the binary arithmatic that happened here.
What i able to find from net is java stores integer in 2's complements which is used to store negative no. 
so from 2's complement

> 128  becomes  10000000

```
after flipping 11111111
```

and adding 1 bit will be

```
10000000
```

Question is how this 10000000
becomes -128?

ANS :

Thanks all i got my ans:

I need to convert 2's complement no 10000000 to decimal  like

```
you first check if the number is negative or positive by looking at the sign bit. If it is positive, simply convert it to decimal. If it is negative, make it positive by inverting the bits and adding one. Then, convert the result to decimal. The negative of this number is the value of the original binary.

    Interpret 11011011 as a two's complement binary number, and give its decimal equivalent.
        First, note that the number is negative, since it starts with a 1.
        Change the sign to get the magnitude of the number.
            1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1
        ¬   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
        +                               1
            0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1
        Convert the magnitude to decimal: 001001012 = 25_16 = 2×16 + 5 = 37_10.
        Since the original number was negative, the final result is -37.
```

So in my case 
 10000000
becomes 
 01111111
adding 1 will be 
 10000000
which is 128 
and original no was negative since the first bit is 1 
so -128

Comment: You said `o/p is -128` and you ask "why is it -127".

Comment: It's really unclear what your question is, to be honest... 128 is indeed 10000000 in binary, which *when treated as an 8-bit 2's complement value* is -127.

Comment: For a byte -(-128) == -128. 0111_1111 = 127, 1000_001 = -127

Comment: sorry @MarkoTopolnik i was testing for 129 so -127

Comment: So what's your actual question? Can you state it, loud and clear? And *by editing the question*, please, not by adding a comment.

Comment: as @JoopEggen said 128 in binary is 10000000 , but in 8bit 2's complement value is -127 , this conversion i don't understand.

Comment: @JonSkeet `10000000` in 2's complement is -128 :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Doh, that's what I meant. Sorry! (Just out of the edit window, unfortunately.)

Comment: @coreJavare There is no conversion. 10000000 is -128 for a signed byte. The top bit determines the sign 1 = negative.  For a 32-bit value, bit 7 is not the top bit, but for an 8-bit value, bit 7 is the top bit.

Answer (score 8):

In binary the int 128 looks like this.

`0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000`

This is 32 bits, 4 bytes.

When you type cast it to byte you get the last 8 binary digits.

`1000 0000`

And this turns out to be the binary representation of the byte -128.

So the result is -128 indeed.

All the byte values in binary go like this:

```
1000 0000  -> - 128
1000 0001  -> - 127
1000 0010  -> - 126
...
1111 1110 -> -2
1111 1111 -> -1
0000 0000 -> 0
0000 0001 -> 1
0000 0010 -> 2
...
0111 1110 -> 126
0111 1111 -> 127
```

This should make it clear to you.

Your confusion is probably because you're thinking of
`1000 0000` as an unsigned byte value. In Java there are
no unsigned bytes. The 1st bit determines the sign.
If there were unsigned bytes (as in some other languages),
this binary value would be indeed `128` and not `-128`.

Comment: @peter.peter what is the value of "11001000" ? Is it -56? If not, how do we calculate it?